# Inconsistent rendering of Date and ID value in Visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I am unable to understand why the inconsistency of the data that is displayed on the VF page. I am displaying Id and Date in the page block table. I am using the apex:column tag to display the data. When I declare the data in the value attribute without any space I get Id with 15 char in length but when I include a space in the value attirbute a 18 char Id is displayed. I am unable to understand why so?
[image]

```
<apex:pageblock>
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
     <apex:column value="{!a.Id}" headerValue="Id without space(15 char)"/>
     <apex:column value=" {!a.Id}" headerValue="Id with space(18 char)"/>
     <apex:column value="{!a.CreatedDate}" headerValue="Date defined in the Value attributes"/>
     <apex:column headerValue="Date not declared in the Value Attribute" >{!a.CreatedDate}</apex:column>
</apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pull only the column, without any spaces, Visualforce displays the field using the out-of-the box interface for that type. Per the [API docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/field_types.htm#i1435616):

> ID fields in the Salesforce user interface contain 15-character, base-62, case-sensitive strings

When you append a string to an ID field, you are converting the value of the ID into a string. As the page is only interested in the value, like a SOQL query or an Apex string method, the "raw" value is returned.

> an 18-digit, case-safe version of the ID is returned by all API calls